# How to pass a JS date object to cloud function for storing it on Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When I write a Date object to my Firestore, all works correctly and I can see a date in the DB stored with the type "timestamp". If I try to pass a Date object to a cloud function, I don't know why but it is an empty object when I store it from the cloud function to the firestore DB.

```
  firebase.functions().httpsCallable("myFunction")({date: new Date()}) <---- // this doesn't work
```

So, I have decided to convert the Date object to a firestore timestamp in the client side before sending it to the cloud function. As follows:

```
  date = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(date);
  firebase.functions().httpsCallable("myFunction")({date})
```

Then, if I get it in the cloud function and store it on my firestore, I see an object with the fields "seconds" and "nanoseconds", but not a timestamp (I mean it is not stored with the type Timestamp)... So when I get this date I cannot apply the method .toDate()

Is there any good way to store the date in this situation as a timestamp and not as an object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The input and output of callable functions deal entirely with JSON, so they are limited to expressing only those types that are allowed in JSON: string, number, boolean, null, object, array.  Date and Timestamp are not among those types.  What the Firebase SDK will do is try to serialize custom objects as JSON, which is not working the way you want - the seconds and nanos fields of the Timestamp are being split up during serialization.

If you have a Date to send from the client, you should just send it as a number.  Instead of passing a Date object, pass the single number inside it (milliseconds since unix epoch):

```
const number = date.getTime()
```

On the receiving side, in Cloud Functions, take the number and convert it back to a Date:

```
const date = new Date(number)
```

Then you can write the Date object to a Firestore document field.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Doug!

Comment: This seems less than ideal. I have complex documents with dates that I need to update to Firestore and also return back to the client. Is there a recommended way of handling these scenarios?

Comment: This does not preserve UTC changes and assumes your date is the same as the server's UTC.

Comment: @CooperScott It's nearly always accepted that UTC dates are passed between APIs.  It's the responsibility of app code to render a date correctly for the user's chosen locale.